# Application using JOGL stays in Limbo when closing

Tags: jogl

I'm writing a game using Java and OpenGL using the JOGL bindings. I noticed that my game doesn't terminate properly when closing the window even though I've set the closing operation of the `JFrame` to `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`. I couldn't track down where the problem was so I've made a small reproduction case. Note that on some computers the program terminates normally when closing the window but on other computers (notably my own) something in the JVM keeps lingering, this causes the `JFrame` to never be disposed and the application to never exit. I haven't found something in common between the computers that had difficulty terminating. All computers had Windows 7, Java 7 and the same version of JOGL and some terminated normally while others had this problem.

The test case is as follows:

```
public class App extends JFrame implements GLEventListener
{   
    private GLCanvas canvas; 

    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) 
    {    
        GL3 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL3();

        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glClear(GL3.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);        

        gl.glFlush();
    }

    // The overrides for dispose (the OpenGL one), init and reshape are empty

    public App(String title, boolean full_screen, int width, int height)
    {      
        //snipped setting the width and height of the JFRAME

        GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL3);
        GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities(profile);

        canvas = new GLCanvas(capabilities);
        canvas.addGLEventListener(this);
        canvas.setSize(getWidth(), getHeight());

        add(canvas);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //!!!

        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose()
    {
        System.out.println("HELP"); // 
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        new App("gltut 01", false, 1280, 720);
    }        
}
```

As you can see this doesn't do much more than adding a `GLCanvas` to the frame and registering the main class as the `GLEventListener`.

So what keeps lingering? I'm not sure. I've made some screenshots.

The application running normally.

[image: While Running]

The application after the `JFrame` is closed, note that the JVM still hasn't exited or printed a return code.

[image: Limbo]

The application after it was force closed.

[image: Force closed]

Note the return code `-1`, so it wasnt just the JVM standing by or something the application really hadn't exited yet.

So what is keeping the application in Limbo? Might it be the circular reference between the GLCanvas and the JFrame? I thought the GC could figure that out. If so how should I deal with that when I want to exit? Is there any other clean-up required when using JOGL? I've tried searching but it doesn't seem to be necessary.

**Edit, to clarify:** there are 2 dispose functions `dispose(GLAutoDrawable arg)` which is a member of `GLEventListener` and `dispose()` which is a member of `JFrame`. The first one is called correctly (but I wouldn't know what to there, destroying the `GLAutoDrawable` or the `GLCanvas` gives an infinite exception loop) the second one is never called.

**Edit 2, October 30th**
I've tried the following suggestions as per the comments:

- Setting the default close operation to `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` doesn't have any effect
- Adding an adapter for the `windowClosing` works and it is properly called but calling `System.exit(0);` there doesn't stop the program, something is left behind.
- Adding a shutdown hook works and shutdown hooks are correctly processed however even adding exit there doesn't help.

Comment: terminates fine for me on win 7 x64

Comment: Exactly what makes this problem so hard. I'm curious what more I can do to dispose/clean JOGL before exiting.

Comment: And if you remove the `dispose()` override?

Comment: I can't, it's an interface I override there not an (abstract) class. So I have to override it.

Comment: public void dispose() is a method in java.awt.Window. You should not override it. Is the provided code up-to-date?

Comment: Ah, yeah confusing that there are 2 disposes. I've removed the java.awt.Window.Dispose override but unfortunately that doesn't mitigate the problem. It was a good tip though since I didn't call the base implementation, however it is never called (the text was never printed, and breakpoints never triggered) so the problem has to be slightly before that.

Comment: If you add a [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29), will it be called?

Comment: Just a lucky guess, but perhaps OpenGL is somehow hanging the program because the frame is not disposed. Try using `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);` instead or adding a custom window listener which both disposes and exits the application.

Comment: Perhaps the difference between the machines is video card drivers? Some drivers may not be playing nice with JOGL, while others are. I think I saw an issue like this with LWJGL.

Comment: Ok I did some more tests: using `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` doesn't help. The windowClosing event is fired but doing `System.exit(0);` there doesn't quit the program either. I've also added a shutdown hook and it is properly called but even adding exit there doesn't help.

Comment: Long shot, but...in your dispose method set everything you can to null and then call System.gc()

Comment: [JOGL forum on JGO](http://www.java-gaming.org/boards/jogl-development/25/view.html). May be a better option than posting what sounds like a library bug, on gamedev.se.

Comment: Nick Wiggill in that case I have to assume it is a bug and I'll try to make bug report and repro case for them there. But it will be very hard from them to find it if they can't reproduce it so I hope one of their machines acts up as well :)

Comment: Just an update, the problem spontaneously disappeared on all systems roughly a week ago. I suspect some update just fixed it but I couldn't nail down which one.

Comment: This is probably something that SO might have better answers for?

Comment: Hi, check this [Hello Triangle](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Jogl_Tutorial#Hello_Triangle) sample in order to see how disposing, it uses Newt